# Fitting an exponential model with two terms.

Tags: exponential-function, estimation

I am struggling to find parameters $A$, $B$, $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}
$ by fitting the following data points (50, 4.220455544),
(100, 4.153915042), (150, 4.061640364) and (200, 3.750447771) to the
function $f(t)=Ae^{-k_{1}t}-Be^{-k_{2}t}$.

I started by creating the following equations:

$f(50)=Ae^{-50k_{1}}-Be^{-50k_{2}}=4.220455544$

$f(100)=Ae^{-100k_{1}}-Be^{-100k_{2}}=4.153915042$

$f(150)=Ae^{-150k_{1}}-Be^{-150k_{2}}=4.061640364$

$f(200)=Ae^{-200k_{1}}-Be^{-200k_{2}}=3.750447771$

Any guidance on how to manually manipulate these equations to solve for
parameters $A$, $B$, $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ (without use of any program including least squares fitting) will be appreciated.

Comment: I don´t think that the resulting equations can be solved algebraically.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore a different approach.

Comment: OK. I hope you´ve already found one.